# How do I get gateway Authcode from Shopify?

Tags: shopify

Shopify receives and stores information received from the gateway after a payment is made. It can be viewed in the orders page right at the bottom under Order History section. The words "customer successfully paid..." is a hyperlink. That information contains the authcode apart from some other credit card information. I just want the authcode. The webhook does not send this information in the xml data. Can you retrieve this through the API or is this not allowed? Thanks

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Any gateway-specific info is provided through the `receipt` parameter on the [Transactions](http://api.shopify.com/transactions.html) API. If the token you're looking for isn't there, it's not available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance. Apparently Shopify won't provide that information due to PCI compliance reasons. The payment provider that does the credit card processing will only send one response to Shopify and I was hoping I could get them to send me a response as well but that was wishful thinking on my part. The finance team will just have to log into Shopify and see that information if they need it.